# Connecting to Remote Database from Windows Forms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a question regarding C# Windows Forms connecting to external hosted databases.

I have a GoDaddy SQLServer 2008 database that I use for my web development database purposes. I am creating a C# windows form and I need that to connect to the database. I know how to connect a C# Windows Form to a local database, so I figured that the only difference would be to use a different connection string.

The connection string I am using is as follows:

```
Data Source=limeoatsdb.db.8996219.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=database; User ID=userid; Password=password;
```

I replaced the values above with dummy values, but obviously in my code they have the correct values.

First of all, is it even possible to connect a C# windows form to a GoDaddy database?

Secondly, if it is possible, any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you get an error message when you try to connect?

Comment: This question is best answered by GD themselves. If they don't allow remote connections to the db, then move hosts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.  GoDaddy [blocks all connections to its databases](http://support.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/does-godaddy-allow-external-sql-server-database-connections/?pc_split_value=1) from systems it doesn't manage.

This is typical of many hosting companies.  It's common that you can only use their databases  from their own systems, for security reasons.

If you need access to your data, you'd need to create some form of intermediary step, such as building an API in your website which could be accessed by your form.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond GoDaddy blocking ports, I should point out this is a bad idea if you plan on distributing the app.

If you allow clients to connect directly to your database, you're essentially leaving the front door wide open.  There'd be nothing stopping me from connecting to your DB server with SQL Management Studio and fiddling with your data.

Think of it this way: in a web app, you'd never give client-side JavaScript direct access to your database.  Instead, it has to go through your app server.

I'd create some kind of server that provides an API that the client Win Form can call.  The server can even be a regular web server that provides REST/SOAP/whatever APIs.  A good place to start might be looking in to WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can connect to a SQL Server database on GoDaddy servers.

It's a feature I've used to access the database through SQL Server Management Studio.

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357147/go-daddy-sql-server-2005-remote-connection

Basically, when creating your database, make sure you check the "Direct Access" option.

Obviously, this is a security issue you must be aware of.